# Extra Space in Nested ul in Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, nested, html-lists, spacing

I am attempting to make a vertical sidebar for a website. There are several main items in the `ul`, and if those items have subcategories, then a new `ul` gets nested within the main `ul` underneath its parent `li` (this is more obvious from the code below). In the latest version of Chrome this displays as it should, yet in the latest Firefox there is a space between the parent `li` and its corresponding subitems in the nested `ul`. Any thoughts on the cause?

Here is the basic html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script>
        </script>
        <style>
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        </head>
<body>
 <ul class="navigation">
   <li>ITEM1</li>
   <li>ITEM2</li>
     <ul class="navigation subitem">
       <li>subitem1</li>
       <li>subitem2</li>
       <li>subitem3</li>
     </ul>
   <li>ITEM3</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.navigation {
    display: inline;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.subitem {
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 0px;

}

.navigation li {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Oxygen';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.subitem li {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    margin-top: 3px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);

}
```

If you load these in both Chrome and Firefox you should be able to see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space is happening because of the "display: inline;" on the .navigation class.  You could try floating it right maybe.

Comment: I can't upvote you yet, but that did it. Thanks. I suppose FF and Webkit have different ways of rendering inline elements?

Comment: WebKit's handling of all sorts of interesting aspects of inline layout is pretty buggy....

Comment: This is invalid HTML5. UL element cannot have UL as a child, it can only have LI. For nested lists, the UL needs to be within the LI tag